# How to send bind collection to child and allow local manipulation without mutating parent collection?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I send a list of items to the child, allow the child to internally select/deselect without affecting the source list?

## Parent

```
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <check-list :items="localObjs"
                        text-property="name"
                        value-property="id" />
          </div>
```

## Child

```
<template>
  <div class="form-control item-container">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2" v-for="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox"
             class="custom-control-input"
             :id="item[valueProperty]"
             v-model="item.isSelected">

      <label class="custom-control-label"
             :for="item[valueProperty]">{{item[textProperty]}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CheckList',
    props: {
      items: Array,
      valueProperty: String,
      textProperty: String
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    }
  };
</script>
```

I have tried binding from parent to child, but that mutates the parent list. I have also tried creating a local copy like below:

```
created: function () {
  this.localItems = this.items.slice();
},
```

And using that but it does not work, nothing is copied. Probably because it tries the copy before the `items` collection is even set.

I would like to update the child list every time the parent one updates, but keep the checkbox selection local to the child and not affect the selection at the parent level.

Answer (score 0):

You should return items in data function and rename the prop items attribute. Then, watch the prop:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CheckList',
    props: {
      prarentItems: Array, // rename
      valueProperty: String,
      textProperty: String
    },
    data(){
      return { items: [] } // local state
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    },
    watch:{
      prarentItems(newValue, oldValue){ // watch prop attribute
        this.items = newValue.map(v => {...v}); // on change, update local state cloning values
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: `newValue.slice(0);` keeps the reactivity. When I check or uncheck the boxes I do not want the original list to be affected.